# How to set Python EVE REST API serving settings for the database on MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, python-3.6, flask-restful, eve, mongodb-atlas

## Problem Summary

I'm trying to setup a python eve REST API server with mongodb at localhost 5000 (http://127.0.0.1:5000/). In the beginning, my mongodb was hosted at localhost 27017, and the API connection worked perfectly. But I want to change the database to a cloud server, so I dumped my db to MongoDB Atlas and tried to revise the MONGO_HOST and add the user credentials in the *settings.py* file. But it didn't work. Here's the code I've tried to revise.

## Before change

*settings.py*

```py
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017
MONGO_DBNAME = 'mydb'
...
SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1:5000'
URL_PREFIX = 'api'
```

## After change

*settings.py*

```py
MONGO_HOST = '<clustername>-mz123.gcp.mongodb.net'
MONGO_USERNAME = 'user'
MONGO_PASSWORD = 'user'
MONGO_DBNAME = 'mydb'
...
SERVER_NAME = '127.0.0.1:5000'
URL_PREFIX = 'api'
```

I've also tried to follow the instruction from [official](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/atlas.html) to access the mongoDB Atlas with pymongo and it worked successfully as below. So I think the problem may exactly be how to set the eve *settings.py* file for connecting to MongoDB Atlas in the correct way.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:password@<clustername>-mz123.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client['db']
col = db['collection']
```

## My questions and thoughts

1. Is there any setting parameter I just missed? I'm not sure if the name of MONGO_HOST is wrong, but I just got it from the instruction on Atlas website.  Or do I need to change the setting to the form like MONGO_URI instead? But I've tried and failed, too. LOL
2. Does the eve REST API serve only for localhost DB (27017) when serving at localhost 5000?
3. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `settings.py`, define your `MONGO_URI` with the param you've used in your `MongoClient` example. See `MONGO_URI` here in the documentation (https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/config.html#global-configuration)

Comment: @victor-chen if this is the correct answer for you, mark as correct to help others too.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I've tried and it worked successfully.  Btw, I deleted the original settings and set only for MONGO_URI and MONGO_DBNAME.